# How to add bootstrap cards in an array variable so that I can add more in future without writing much code ?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a card to store data for website (though not sure if it is best way to implement image with data) . Like this:

```
enter code here<div class="row">
```

```
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img height="auto align-self-strech col-xs-3" class="card-img-top" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ex9nL9iB34E/Tf8gTFiGqdI/AAAAAAAAE1A/lx8E4lYwVR0/s1600/Ahoban++by+Habib+Wahid+album+2011.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

         <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">আহ্বান - হাবীব</h5>
    <p class="card-text">হাবীবের নতুন একক এলবাম</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">দেখুন</a>
  </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
    <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFgR41SZX2C-ovvvfCZ7mwqzPvyj6Q8CMhZ31yjaKLIoPUj-Ss7A">
         <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">বেষ্ট অফ মিনার</h5>
    <p class="card-text">গান বাংলা থেকে প্রকাশিত মিনারের একক এলবাম</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">দেখুন</a>
  </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

How to insert them in a array in javascript to interact with database ? Currently I am using Mongodb. 
Also, do I have to make an empty card with class images, name etc. to be pushed by database ?

Comment: why dont you use append method()

Comment: where is the javascript in here ?

Comment: It's an ejs file actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to create a card in HTML and fill it with data from your database. This can be done in numerous ways, including manually. But I recommend you to use a framework for this. Such as [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org), [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/) or something like that.

You create the template you want to fill and use the framework to call that template and fill it with data. The database should not matter.

Comment: Thanks Josip. So, do I need array to store or insert new cards in the framework or they will be be allocated automatically ?

Comment: Depends on how you create your backend, in most cases the backend provides a JSON file containing your object. You can than parse the JSON and put the pieces in place.